# Rails/Tire – Prevent attribute from being indexed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tire

I'm trying to create a custom mapping using Rails (3.2.8), Tire, and ElasticSearch.

I'd like "title" and "description" to be the only searchable/indexed attributes... but, I just can't seem to make this work:

Below is my model:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :attachment, :attachment_thumbnail

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  tire.mapping do
    indexes :id, :type => 'integer', :index => :not_analyzed, :include_in_all => false
    indexes :attachment, :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed, :include_in_all => false
    indexes :attachment_thumbnail, :type => 'string', :index => :not_analyzed, :include_in_all => false
    indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
  end

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `index` to `no`:

```
indexes :id, :type => 'integer', :index => :no, :include_in_all => false
indexes :attachment, :type => 'string', :index => :no, :include_in_all => false
indexes :attachment_thumbnail, :type => 'string', :index => :no, :include_in_all => false
indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
```

Using `not_analysed` will only prevent the field being broken down into tokens - it will still be included in the index.

See [core types](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#string) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the mapping, you should reindex entire data again. **If it is a test data** remove the indices. Create the indices and index the data again. I guess you tried to add :include_in_all => false after indexing the data.

Comment: If you really don't want the fields to be added in the index why add them in the first place? The include_in_all option is used such that those fields are not searchable but can be used in query filters. If you add that option to the field in mapping after indexing data, you have to reindex the data for that to come into effect. Or else old mapping exists as it is.